# Regular expression to match everything to the end of a string, excluding the last character if it's a slash (/)

Tags: python, regex

Currently, I have the following Python regex:

```
r'^https?://(www.)?domain.com/?(?P<path>.*)/?$'
```

That I'm replacing with:

```
r'/\g<path>/'
```

This works fine except in the scenario where the last character of the string is a slash (/). In that case, the `.*` greedily consumes the last `/`, so the subbed string ends up as `/path//`

Essentially, I'm stripping the domain from an absolute path, turning it into a relative path, and trying to ensure that the relative path both begins and ends with a `/`.

Any idea how I can exclude the last character from the match if and only if it's a `/`? It seems I'll probably need some sort of look-ahead, but I'm not sure exactly how to construct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make the asterisk lazy:

```
r'^https?://(www.)?domain.com/?(?P<path>.*?)/?$'
```

The `$` at the end ensures that the entire string will be matched, and a trailing slash, if present, will always be matched by the `/?`.

Comment: Gee whiz. I considered that but dismissed it, because for some crazy reason, I was thinking that would prevent having `/`s in between. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use regular expressions for this, use the [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse) module instead.

Example from the docs:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> o = urlparse('http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html')
>>> o
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.cwi.nl:80', path='/%7Eguido/Python.html',
            params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> o.scheme
'http'
>>> o.port
80
>>> o.geturl()
'http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html'
```

Comment: Normally, I would agree, but I actually simplified my regex for the purposes of the question. It's actually being run against only a subset of domains that are dynamically inserted into the regex, so urlparse would still require that I run a regex on the domain part to see if I should even alter the URL. So, it's simpler to just use a regex for the whole thing.